# Codeigniter with Wordpress integration

Tags: wordpress, authentication, codeigniter

Is there any way to use custom Wordpress installed authentication with Codeigniter framework?

Comment: please clarify what you mean... Use Wordpress.com authentication for Codeigniter?

Comment: what i ment was custom wordpress instalation with Codeigniter, do you have any clue?

Comment: Please give a much detailed explanation of what your goals are, how you want it to work, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It would take some custom work to find the Wordpress auth library, insert it into CI, and then get the look-and-feel right for your app.

A better way would be to use an auth library that's been specially developed for CI, like the wonderful [TankAuth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/)...

Answer (score 1):

There is a command called is logged in or something as I remember that I used in a php script. So if you log into wordpress, and use it in the CI auth it might work that way.